# Sorting an NSMutableArrray that contains Arrays?

Tags: nsmutablearray

I have a class called userResults which looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface userResults : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *resultsMix;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *resultsSaving;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *resultsBlendComponent1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *resultsBlendComponent2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *resultsTotalProtein;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *resultsPricePerPound;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *resultsPricePerPoint;

@end
```

With a implementation like this:

```
#import "userResults.h"

@implementation userResults

@end
```

I will build up multiple values of this in an NSMutableArray called results.

I want to be able to sort the records in results on the *resultsSaving field.

I have populated two arrays, results1 and results2, and stuck them in the larger array, and then I try to sort with this code.

```
results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:results1,results2,nil];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"resultsSaving" ascending:YES];
[results sortUsingDescriptors:sort];
```

Doesn't work. I think that I may have some conceptual problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bryan

Answer (score 0):

After much scouring of the internet, I found this answer:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"resultsSaving"
                                            ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
sortedArray = [results sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

What is odd is that you can't do descending, but must give a ascending:NO. That is pretty weird.